# Split EditFrom to several components

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I would like to split a form into several subcomponents.

However, changes within the subcomponents are not reflected in the main component.

If I change something in field 1a, all other fields change as well. The same applies to field 1b.
However, if I change something in 2a, 2b, 3a, or 3b, only the data in 2a,2b, 3a, and 3b will change.

How to get the right context?

`Form.razor`

```
<h1>Field 1a and 1b</h1>
<CascadingValue Value="@TestObject" Name="TestObject">
    <EditForm Model="@TestObject">
        <MgInputText @bind-Value="TestObject.Address"/>
        <MgInputText @bind-Value="TestObject.Address" />
        <Test />
    </EditForm>
</CascadingValue>
```

`MgInputText.razor`

```
@inherits Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputText
<input @attributes="@AdditionalAttributes" @bind="@CurrentValueAsString" @bind:event="oninput" />
```

`Test.razor`

```
<h1>Field 2a and 2b - GroupBox</h1>
<GroupBox>
    <Title>TestData</Title>
    <ChildContent>
        <MgInputText @bind-Value="TestObject.Address" />
        <MgInputText @bind-Value="TestObject.Address" />
    </ChildContent>
</GroupBox>
<h2>Field 3a and 3b - Not in Component</h2>
<MgInputText @bind-Value="TestObject.Address" />
<MgInputText @bind-Value="TestObject.Address" />

@code{
    [CascadingParameter(Name = "TestObject")]
    public TestObject TestObject{ get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Read under "Updating Cascading Values" on the attached ... https://chrissainty.com/understanding-cascading-values-and-cascading-parameters/

Comment: I think the problem is that you are expecting the values in the parent component to "automatically" update when you update the field `Address` in the child component.  The actual value in the cascaded object has updated, but the parent hasn't re-rendered and thus updated the `MgInputText` value.  There's no intrinsic system to flood updates up (or down) the tree.  You need to do that yourself through an event model driven by edit state.  You pay a penalty for complexity!

Comment: The answer from Nail help to find the Problem. Cascading value only talks to the from parent to child and not the other way :(.

Comment: Do you have a solution?  I can post one for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom component like this :

```
@using System.Linq.Expressions
@typeparam TValue
<input value="@Value" @oninput="HandleInput" />
@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private EditContext EditContext { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public TValue Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<TValue> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<TValue>> ValueExpression { get; set; }

    private FieldIdentifier _fieldIdentifier;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _fieldIdentifier = FieldIdentifier.Create(ValueExpression);
    }

    private async Task HandleInput(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        if (EditContext != null)
        {
            EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged(_fieldIdentifier);
        }
        await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync((TValue)args.Value);
    }

}
```

Then Call the custom component wherever you want :

```
<AttributeInputs @bind-Value="ViewModel.Model.Description"></AttributeInputs>
```